# Is it sound to wrap a list item in an anchor?

Tags: html, background-image, listitem

I have a group of images which each have their own links. I want the images to be in a list (`<ul><li>` .. etc) and have each item have a different `background-image`.

Would I run into any issues with something like this?

```
<ul>
<a href="#"><li class="1"></li></a>
<a href="#"><li class="2"></li></a>
<a href="#"><li class="3"></li></a>
<a href="#"><li class="4"></li></a>
<a href="#"><li class="5"></li></a>
<a href="#"><li class="6"></li></a>
</ul>
```

Comment: so what would an alternative to it be?

Comment: you could put the link inside the `li`, couldn't you?

Answer (score 15):

You would do better to write it like this

```
<ul>
<li class="1"><a href="#"></a></li>
<li class="2"><a href="#"></a></li>
<li class="3"><a href="#"></a></li>
</ul>
```

Then you could add the `background-image` to either the `a` or the `li`.

**However**, you would style the `a`s as `display:block` and give them the same `height` and `width` of the `li`.  That way the background-image would show and the entire `li` would be clickable.

Answer (score 6):

It is not valid HTML because the only thing allowed in an `<ul>` element is `<li>`s.

Answer (score 3):

It's not [valid HTML.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html#h-10.2)

```
<!ELEMENT UL - - (LI)+                 -- unordered list -->
```

Comment: Just curious, where is this syntax explained? I read this in the documentation, but would not, on my own, come to the conclusion that this means only `li` tags can be children of lists.