# display: inline not working even with float

Tags: html, css, css-float, display

I'm trying to create a horizontal nav bar using CSS and display: inline; but I'm having no joy with it. Using `<ul><li>`, I am getting a vertical list rather than a horizontal one. I've Googled the web and poured over SO but can't find a fix.

```css
#menu ul {
  height: 15px;
  padding: 8px 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
#menu li {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  float: left;
}
.logo {
  font-family: 'Mr De Haviland', cursive;
  font-size: 32px;
}
.logo a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#nav a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#nav {
  max-width: 600px;
  width: auto;
  height: 35px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 3px 2px 3px #666666;
  background-color: #999999;
  border-radius: 8px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-gb">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Mr+De+Haviland' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
  <title>Anthony Jones</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main">
    <div class="logo">
      <p align="center">
        <a class="logo" href="index.html">Anthony Jones</a>
      </p>
    </div>

    <div id="nav">
      <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
        <a href="about.html">
          <li>About</li>
        </a>
        <a href="cv.html">
          <li>Curriculum Vitae</li>
        </a>
        <a href="services.html">
          <li>Services</li>
        </a>
        <a href="random.html">
          <li>Random</li>
        </a>
        <a href="contact.html">
          <li>Contact Me</li>
        </a>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

The `ul style="list-style-type: none;"` in the `<style>` tag is there because I couldn't remove the bullet points within the **index.css** file, this was the only solution I could find.

I've tried many variations on the code, rearranged it, deleted and started over and still no joy. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Tony welcome to SO, could you edit and make it more clear what you want to achieve?

Comment: When you float a element becomes a block element, you can´t set `display:inline` if the element is floated.

Comment: Exactly. stop the float on the `li` as well

Comment: Great! please don't forget to check the checkmark next to the top answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 1: you can't wrap an `a` tag around `li`. `a` tag must be inside `li`.

Like this:

```
<div id="nav">
<ul style="list-style-type: none;">
<li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
<li><a href="cv.html">Curriculum Vitae</a></li>
<li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
<li><a href="random.html">Random</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact Me</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

## 2: Set `li` to `display: inline`

Like this:

```
#nav li {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: As you can see I have done this, as well as inline-block, no joy.

Comment: @Tony Your `a` are still outside of the `li`. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-gb">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Mr+De+Haviland' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
<title>Anthony Jones</title>
<style>
#menu ul {
height: 15px;
padding: 8px 0px;
margin: 0px;
}

#nav li {
text-decoration: none;
display: inline;
padding: 20px;
float: left;
}

.logo {
font-family: 'Mr De Haviland', cursive;
font-size: 32px;
}

.logo a {
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
}

#nav a {
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
}

#nav {
max-width: 600px;
width: auto;
height: 35px;
font-size: 16px;
font-family: Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
text-align: center;
text-shadow: 3px 2px 3px #666666;
background-color: #999999;
border-radius: 8px;
list-style-type: none;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="main">
<div class="logo">
<p align="center">
<a class="logo" href="index.html">Anthony Jones</a>
</p>
</div>  

<div id="nav">
<ul style="list-style-type: none;">
<li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
<li><a href="cv.html">Curriculum Vitae</a></li>
<li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
<li><a href="random.html">Random</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact Me</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#nav li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Your list item was set to display as `list-item`, and not `inline block`.

These styles are doing nothing for you:

```
#menu li {
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
padding: 20px;
float: left;
}
```

An element with the id `#menu`is not present in your mark-up.

```css
.logo {
font-family: 'Mr De Haviland', cursive;
font-size: 32px;
}

.logo a {
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
}

#nav a {
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
}

#nav {
max-width: 600px;
width: auto;
height: 35px;
font-size: 16px;
font-family: Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
text-align: center;
text-shadow: 3px 2px 3px #666666;
background-color: #999999;
border-radius: 8px;
list-style-type: none;
}

#nav li {
    display: inline-block;
}

#nav ul {
    padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-gb">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Mr+De+Haviland' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
<title>Anthony Jones</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="main">
<div class="logo">
<p align="center">
<a class="logo" href="index.html">Anthony Jones</a>
</p>
</div>  

<div id="nav">
    <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="cv.html">Curriculum Vitae</a></li>
        <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="random.html">Random</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Me</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

</div>
</body>
```

1. Indent your mark-up properly so it's easier to read, and when necessary, to debug as well.
2. Avoid wrapping `block` elements (like `<li>`) with `inline` elements (like `<a>`), this is invalid mark-up (see: [Is it sound to wrap a list item in an anchor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7275523/is-it-sound-to-wrap-a-list-item-in-an-anchor))

Comment: In HTML5 is posible wrap block element  with `a`, not with others inline elements: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element --> "The a element may be wrapped around entire paragraphs, lists, tables, and so forth, even entire sections, so long as there is no interactive content within (e.g. buttons or other links)"   Although in this case it does not seem right because the structure of a list is `ul> li> other elements`

Comment: @blonfu Thanks for clarifying that! The link was helpful too.